# How do I copy a file back one directory?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to this and working on mini test projects.

I have my source folder.  In here is a folder called test.  I want to copy a file from the test folder to my source folder.  Can I do this without putting in the entire file path?

```
...
shutil.copy('/test/1.txt', '../')
...
```

So just copy the file from the test folder and replace it with the file that is one folder back.

Comment: Do you mean one folder up from current (cwd), or one folder up from the source file?

Comment: I also can't quite tell what you are asking. Pehaps including short example of what your directory/file structure would look like before and after would explain what you mean more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quiet sure if I understood you 100%, but here how I would do it if an absolute path for your file is ok:

```py
import os
import shutil

file_path =  '/test/1.txt'
shutil.copy(file_path, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file_path), '../'))
```

Otherwise if you realy don't want any absolute file path, it depends on your current working directory.

Let's say, your current working directory would be your source directory: `/`

Then the script could be written down like:

```py
import os
import shutil

file_path =  'test/1.txt'
shutil.copy(file_path, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file_path), '../'))
```

Otherwise, if your current working directory is where the file is located, then it get's simplified just to:

```py
import shutil

shutil.copy('1.txt', '../')
```